# BigQuery batch loading into partitioned table

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm loading data into BQ partitioned table from GCS. Every day one date partition.
How I can use WRITE_TRANCATE for partition, not for the whole table?
I want to overwrite partition data.
How it should be implemented?

I'm using code like this
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-partitioned

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the partition you want to overwrite (instead of a whole table):

```
table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name$20210527"
```